# URL string in mySQL database and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I am having trouble with URLs stored in my database not displaying properly. Here is my code:

```
    $sqlCommand = 
       "SELECT  rotator.title, rotator.imageURL, rotator.targetURL, rotator.caption  FROM rotator   
        WHERE ( ( rotator.visible = '1' )
        OR ( rotator.visible = '2' AND ( NOW() BETWEEN rotator.schedstart AND rotator.schedstop ) ) )
        ORDER BY rotator.displayorder ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));

    $rotatorsDisplay = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $rotatorstitle = $row["title"];
        $rotatorsimg = $row["imgURL"];
        $rotatorsURL = $row["targetURL"];
        $rotatorscaption = $row["caption"];

        $rotatorsDisplay .= '<li>
                <a href="'. $rotatorsURL .'"><img src="'. $rotatorsimg .'"></a>
                <div id="title">'. $rotatorstitle .'</div>
                <div class="caption">'. $rotatorscaption .'</div>
            </li>';
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
```

The thing that's causing me trouble is the $rotatorsimg variable. In the database, I have manually entered values for rotator.imageURL that look like this: 'images/rotator/name.jpg' but when I query them from the database, add them to the $rotatorsDisplay variable, then output them with this code:

```
    <?php echo $rotatorsDisplay; ?>
```

All I get in the resulting page is this:

```
    <a href="doctor.php"><img src=""></a>
```

I'm pretty sure the reason this isn't working is the slashes in the URL. I'm also pretty sure I need to somehow encode/convert HTML to strip special characters from code I enter into my database, then decode/convert it back to HTML when I output it, but since I entered this info manually into the database using phpMyAdmin, I haven't worked out how to do this yet.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong index key.

```
$rotatorsimg = $row["imgURL"];
```

should probably be

```
$rotatorsimg = $row["imageURL"];
```

since that's what you're querying from the database.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it had to be something pretty obvious.